# Cannot run 'display' after ImageMagick install on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, imagemagick

I'm trying to install ImageMagick to my Ubuntu box. I've run the following command:

```
sudo aptitude install imagemagick
```

Now whenever I try to run 'display' from the command line, I get an error saying

```
display: delegate library support not built-in `' (X11) @ display.c/DisplayImageCommand/1888.
```

I can certainly include more details if asked, but at the moment I'm not sure what else to include.

I'm running Ubuntu 9.10.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that your installation of ImageMagick does not support this operation.  Unfortunately, this capability was not enabled at the time ImageMagick was compiled.  If this is a package supplied with the operating system (which is most likely the case), you will need to file a bug report or otherwise let the Ubuntu community know about this problem, so that the package maintainer can fix this problem.

Alternatively, you can build from source; at the configure stage, type the following command:

```
./configure --with-modules
```

The `--with-modules` argument is what enables this feature in ImageMagick.  See [this ImageMagick forum entry](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=18618).

Answer (score 2):

According to [this imagemagick forum topic](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=10896), the 'delegate support not built in' message means that on *compile time* some external library was disabled because of unsatisfied dependencies, and to make it work you need to install other version of package, either compiled from source or taken from other Ubuntu version.

I ran the `display` command on my XUbuntu 9.10, and it worked fine, so this command is probably fixed in later versions of Ubuntu. Can you post yours?

Comment: I understand that it can't find a package, but which package?  Is it X11?  Because I'm pretty sure I have X11 installed correctly.  Although I've been wrong before.

Comment: No! It does not attempts find packages in runtime: it says that there were no **built-in** support: it is broken by *package maintainer*, not you.