# ImageMagick "display" command returns "delegate library support not built-in" error

Tags: ubuntu, imagemagick

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cannot run 'display' after ImageMagick install on Ubuntu](https://superuser.com/questions/99915/cannot-run-display-after-imagemagick-install-on-ubuntu)

When I enter:

```
# display logo.gif
```

I get the following error:

```
display: delegate library support not built-in `' (X11) @     error/display.c/DisplayImageCommand/1903.
```

My OS is Ubuntu 10.10.